# Use cases for hotswapping Akka actors

Tags: actor, akka

The Akka 1.1.3 documentation states that "[t]he `become` method is useful for many different things, but a particular nice example of it is in example where it is used to implement a Finite State Machine (FSM)."  What are some other use cases for hotswapping an Akka actor's implementation at runtime?

The `actorClass` method in the `ActorRef` trait is deprecated with the message, "Will be removed without replacement, doesn't make any sense to have in the face of `become` and `unbecome`."  Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Question 1: Encoding variable behavior:

http://klangism.tumblr.com/post/968180337/dining-hakkers

For Question 2:

Knowing the backing classname of an actor is pointless, since it will not tell you anything about the behavior. It also will not work reliably with remoting since the service can be re-bound, and there's no exchange of such information. Essentially actorClassName violates tell-don't-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do a software upgrade without interrupting the service. You may load the new behavior dynamically and then hotswap it with the old one.